# output is wrong when i use OpenACC

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, openacc, pgi

I'm going to optimize this code by openacc, but the output computations are zero. I would appreciate the opportunity to help me in this way and use your guidances to achieve success and solve my problem.

Impatiently,I am looking forward to hear you soon.
King regards,

Sajjad Mohammadi

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <assert.h>
  #include <openacc.h>
  #include<time.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <malloc.h>
 // #include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

  #define NX 4
  #define NY 4
  #define NZ 4


  int main(void)
  {
  int i, j,p, k;

  static double A[NX-1][NY-1][NZ-1]={10.} ,B[NX-1][NY-1][NZ-1]={10.},C[NX-1][NY-1][NZ-1]={10.};
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen("B-and-A.csv", "w");


    #pragma acc data copyin(B,C),copyout(A)
    {
for (p = 0; p <=2; p++) {
#pragma acc kernels  loop private(i,j,k)
 for ( i = 1; i < NX - 1; i++ ) {

        for ( j = 0; j < NY - 1; j++ ) {
            for ( k = 0; k < NZ - 1; k++ ) {
        A[i][j][k] = A[i][j][k]+2.
         + 1.*( B[i][j+1][k] + C[i][j][k] )
         + 1.*( C[i][j][k+1] + B[i][j][k] );
}
}
}

fprintf(file,"%e\n",A[2][2][2]);
}
}
  fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: You *do* know that array indexes are zero-based? So if you declare an array of e.g. `3` elements (like `NX-1` is) then start indexing on `1`, then your arrays effectively have only two elements, at index `1` and `2`. That's quite a lot (in percent) of wasted space in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your OpenACC directives.

First, since "A" is in a "copyout" clause, it is not initialized on the device.  But you're using "A" on both sides of the equation so need to put "A" in a "copy" directive instead.

Second, your data region spans over the "p" loop so isn't copied back until after the end of the loop.  However, you're printing "A" for each iteration of "p".  Hence, you're not printing the updated value from the device.  To fix, add an "#pragma acc update self(A)" before you print the value.

Comment: Thank you for your all your help.